# How do I repeat certain steps in Spark Streaming

Tags: java, spark-streaming

I'm working on a Java program in Spark Stream which requires process tasks has many steps. The problem is every tasks has different steps to run. In traditional program it may looks like that

```
Params params = initParams();
for (Step step : task.steps()) {
    Result result = step.execute(params);
    params = result.convertToParams();
}
```

Because the steps are not hard coded. I have to use loop to walk through all steps one by one. But how do I write those steps in Spark Streaming and link them together?

PS: I can't put all those steps in one single function call because there are some steps I need to use RDD joinByKey operation.

Thanks.

Bruce

Comment: By the way the later steps are depends on previous steps, must be executed in order.

Comment: Could you give an example on how this should look like in Spark Streaming?

Comment: I found in Apache Flink has the concept called Iteration. Does Spark has the same operation?